# How to hide the Bottom action bar in React Native

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I have a problem in React Native, I want to hide the bottom action bar which is just below my tab bar nav.

I want to make a Disney + App clone and this thing stuck me:

This is th bottom of my app with the little action bar
[image: This is th bottom of my app with the little action bar]

The Original App without this action bar
[image: The Original App without this action bar]

I don't know how to do this.
Here is my App.js code :

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import React from 'react';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import { Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons';
import HomeScreen from './screens/HomeScreen';
import SearchScreen from './screens/SearchScreen';
import DownloadScreen from './screens/DownloadScreen';
import ProfilScreen from './screens/ProfilScreen';
import { iconSize, prefix, activeTabColor, inactiveTabColor, tabBarBackgroundColor, appTheme } from './utils/Constants';
import { ImageBackground } from 'react-native';
import DisneyImageBackground from './assets/home-background.png';

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

export default function App() {

  const getTabColor = (focused) => {
    return focused ? activeTabColor : inactiveTabColor;
  }

  const getScreenOptions = (route) => {

  }

  return (
    <ImageBackground source={DisneyImageBackground} style={{ flex: 1 }} resizeMode="cover">

      <NavigationContainer theme={appTheme}>
        <Tab.Navigator 
          screenOptions={
            ({ route }) => ({
              tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => {
                if (route.name === 'Home') {
                  return <Ionicons name={`${prefix}-home`} color={getTabColor(focused)} size={iconSize} />
                } else if (route.name === 'Search') {
                  return <Ionicons name={`${prefix}-search`} color={getTabColor(focused)} size={iconSize} />
                } else if (route.name === 'Download') {
                  return <Ionicons name={`${prefix}-download`} color={getTabColor(focused)} size={iconSize} />
                } else if (route.name === 'Profil') {
                  return <Ionicons name={`${prefix}-person`} color={getTabColor(focused)} size={iconSize} />
                }
              },
            })
          }
          tabBarOptions={{
            activeBackgroundColor: tabBarBackgroundColor,
            inactiveBackgroundColor: tabBarBackgroundColor,
            showLabel: false,
            style: {
              height: 55,
              borderTopWidth: 0.2,
              borderTopColor: '#2f313d'
            }
          }}>
          <Tab.Screen name='Home' component={HomeScreen} />
          <Tab.Screen name='Search' component={SearchScreen} />
          <Tab.Screen name='Download' component={DownloadScreen} />
          <Tab.Screen name='Profil' component={ProfilScreen} />
        </Tab.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    </ImageBackground>


  );
}
```

If anyone has the solution, that would be really helpful :)
Thank you

Comment: I am not sure if I follow you. But what you want is to remove the white area at the bottom, right? it is called the safe areas and you can read the doc to handle it. https://reactnavigation.org/docs/handling-safe-area/

Comment: @MicFung Yes, that's it. I want to delete the safe area. Thanks for the doc

Comment: Avoid using SafeArea in the first place. Yes, u will get the top margin for the StatusBar area... using SafeArea, but it will also add marginBottom for the ActionBar to be visible

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code

App.js

```
import React, {useRef, useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import {
  FlatList,
  SafeAreaView,
  ScrollView,
  StatusBar,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  useColorScheme,
  View,
  Image,
  TouchableOpacity,
  TextInput,
} from 'react-native';
import Home from './routes';
import {createAppContainer} from 'react-navigation';

const AppRoot = createAppContainer(Home);

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this._navigator = null;
  }
  render() {
    alert('HI');
    return <AppRoot />;
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: 'red',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
});

export default App;
```

Routes.js

```
import React from 'react';

import {
  StyleSheet,
  View,
  Text,
} from 'react-native';
import {createStackNavigator} from 'react-navigation-stack';
import {createBottomTabNavigator} from 'react-navigation-tabs';

import Profile from './Profile';

const NotifyNavigation = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Profile: {
      screen: Profile,
      navigationOptions: {
        gesturesEnabled: false,
      },
    },
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Profile',
    defaultNavigationOptions: {
      headerTitleStyle: {
      },
    },
  },
);
NotifyNavigation.navigationOptions = ({navigation}) => {
  let {routeName} = navigation.state.routes[navigation.state.index];
  let navigationOptions = {};
  navigationOptions.tabBarVisible = routeName === 'Profile';
  return navigationOptions;
};

const ProfileNavigation = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Profile: {
      screen: Profile,
      navigationOptions: {
        gesturesEnabled: false,
      },
    },
  },
  {
    defaultNavigationOptions: {
      headerTitleStyle: {
        // fontFamily: 'SFProText-Regular',
      },
    },
  },
);
ProfileNavigation.navigationOptions = ({navigation}) => {
  let {routeName} = navigation.state.routes[navigation.state.index];
  let navigationOptions = {};
  navigationOptions.tabBarVisible = routeName === 'Profile';
  return navigationOptions;
};

const ScheduleNavigation = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Profile: {
      screen: Profile,
      navigationOptions: {
        gesturesEnabled: false,
      },
    },
  },
  {
    defaultNavigationOptions: {
      headerTitleStyle: {
        // fontFamily: 'SFProText-Regular',
      },
    },
  },
);
ScheduleNavigation.navigationOptions = ({navigation}) => {
  let {routeName} = navigation.state.routes[navigation.state.index];
  let navigationOptions = {};
  navigationOptions.tabBarVisible = routeName === 'Profile';
  return navigationOptions;
};

/**
 * TabNavigation
 */
const TabNavigation = createBottomTabNavigator(
  {
    CalenderTab: {
      screen: ScheduleNavigation,
      navigationOptions: {
        tabBarIcon: ({focused}) => {
          return (
            <View style={styles.iconContainer}>
              <Text style={{color: 'white'}}>User</Text>
            </View>
          );
        },
      },
    },

    NotifyTab: {
      screen: NotifyNavigation,
      navigationOptions: {
        tabBarIcon: ({focused}) => {
          return (
            <View style={styles.iconContainer}>
              <Text style={{color: 'white'}}>Movies</Text>
            </View>
          );
        },
      },
    },

    ProfileTab: {
      screen: ProfileNavigation,
      navigationOptions: {
        tabBarIcon: ({focused}) => {
          return (
            <View style={styles.iconContainer}>
              <Text style={{color: 'white'}}>Series</Text>
            </View>
          );
        },
      },
    },
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'ProfileTab',

    navigationOptions: {
      gesturesEnabled: false,
    },
    tabBarOptions: {
      showLabel: false,
      style: {
        paddingTop: 5,
        backgroundColor: 'black',
        borderTopColor: '#e7e7e7',
        borderTopWidth: 2,
        height: 65,
      },
    },
  },
);

/**
 * Application Root
 */
const Root = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Main: TabNavigation,
  },
  {
    headerMode: 'none',
    mode: 'modal',
    navigationOptions: {
      gesturesEnabled: false,
    },
  },
);

// const AppContainer = createAppContainer(Root);
export default Root;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  iconContainer: {
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: 'red',
    width: 50,
    height: 50,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
});
```

Screen1(Profile.js)

```
import React from 'react';
import {View, Text} from 'react-native';

export default class Profile extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View
        style={{
          flex: 1,
          backgroundColor: '#ddd',
          justifyContent: 'center',
          alignItems: 'center',
        }}>
        <Text>Screen</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

And this is the output:
[image]